# AngularJs - Bootstrap Toggle not able to get check box values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#demos) for my AngularJs project. I created angular directive for this plugin.

```
myApp.directive('iosToggle', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).bootstrapToggle(scope.$eval(attrs.iosToggle));
        }
    };
});
```

and using directive in my view

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myInterview" data-ios-toggle="toggle" data-style="ios" data-onstyle="info" data-size="small" data-on="On" data-off="Off" ng-model="myData.myInterview">
```

I am getting same design and able to on or off, but When i submit the form, i am not getting check box values.

Comment: you must watch and chage the ng-model as well!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have updated my directive with $watch on change and then updated the model. It works.

```
myApp.directive('iosToggle', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        replace: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ngModel) {
            // update model from Element
            var updateModelFromElement = function() {
                // If modified
                var checked = $element.prop('checked');
                if (checked !== ngModel.$viewValue) {
                    // Update ngModel
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(checked);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            };

            // Update input from Model
            var updateElementFromModel = function() {
                $element.trigger('change');
            };

            // Observe: Element changes affect Model
            $element.on('change', function() {
                updateModelFromElement();
            });

            // Observe: ngModel for changes
            $scope.$watch(function() {
                    return ngModel.$viewValue;
                }, function() {
                updateElementFromModel();
            });

            // Initialise BootstrapToggle
            $timeout(function() {
                $element.bootstrapToggle();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Works well, source is there: https://gist.github.com/dave-newson/f6c5e9c2f3bc315e292c